# Accumulate values in array without reducing into single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to do something really similar to `reduce` with values in my array, but I do not want to sum it all up into one value. I want to carry on the summed up value and insert the increment into each consecutive value in the array.

Like this:

```
const array = [{ number: 6, value: 10 }, { number: 5, value: 12 }, { number: 2, value: 5 }]

// Do something like this
const newArray = array.reduce((accumulated, item) => {
  return {  
    number: (100 / item.number) + accumulated.value || 0,
    value: ((100 / item.number) + accumulated.value || 0) * item.value
  }
}, 0)

// But the result should be something like this
newArray = [{ number: 6, value: 10 }, { number: 30, value: 360 }, { ...and so on }]
```

How can this be achieved? ES6 with/without lodash preferred.

Comment: I don't get the math behind `{ number: 20 value: 240 }`. The logic in the `.reduce` callback doesn't look to do that. Did you mean `{ number: 30, value: 360 }`? Can you clarify the logic you're looking for?

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are absolutely right, my math was wrong. Thanks. I am basically trying to find a way to `map` but with an accumulator, so I thought `reduce` was the nearest thing

Comment: How does a sum accumulator result into those values? The logic is unclear here. You need to explain in your question the math logic, because even your own example there doesn't produce the values you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input and output items are one-to-one, I think using `.map` would be more intuitive than `.reduce` - you can keep an outside variable for the last object returned.

```js
const array = [{ number: 6, value: 10 }, { number: 5, value: 12 }, { number: 2, value: 5 }]

let lastReturn = array.shift();
const newArray = [lastReturn].concat(array.map(({ number, value }) => {
  const newObj = {  
    number: (100 / number) + lastReturn.value || 0,
    value: ((100 / number) + lastReturn.value || 0) * value
  };
  lastReturn = newObj;
  return newObj;
}));
console.log(newArray);
```

While it'd be technically *possible* to use `.reduce` for this (you can use `.reduce` to achieve anything related to array iteration, `.map` makes more sense here.